# Parallel data ADC with GPIO

Tags: gpio

I am currently building a Multichannel analyzer featuring a Pi3. A requirement is very fast ADC acquisition. SPI and I2C are all too slow i.e. millisecond sample times. It seems the only converters that are fast enough (and 12-16 bit) are parallel data transfer. The Pi i/o seems to scatter its data bits randomly over its ports I can't seem to find a contiguous byte much less word. How can one use a "data bus" with the Pi, not using bus expansion shift registers (just another way of saying serial port) I need a minimum of 8 bits for a 2 byte read. Or have I hit a dead end?
Thank You
Todd

Comment: SPI too slow?  A 100 ksps shouldn't be that hard on a Pi3.

Comment: The UART will work at 1 Mbps, so using a parallel input shift register should net you 125 KB/s.

Comment: I would really like to get the sample acquired and read in 5 uS, 10 uS at the most (1 uS would be a dream). All of the ADC's I have found with SPI are much slower than that. The only ones faster in serial are some formats I'm really not familiar with. They seem to be for audio/video codecs.

Comment: 1 usecs would be a dream.  If the sample size is 4 bits you might conceivably get 5 usecs, if it is 8 10 usecs, but you will only be able to do it using an existing bus that is implemented in hardware.  There is no possibility of fabricating some kind of parallel interface in software working at that speed using the GPIOs, particularly within the context of a multi-tasking OS.

Comment: @goldilocks Actually pigpio can sample GPIO 0-31 at 1 MHz.  I don't recommend it as it uses 25% of the CPU for the sampling (the default 5µs sampling rate has an overhead of about 6%).  The problem with parallel data is clocking the data into the Pi.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the need to "clock in" parallel data. Normally it's serial data which is synchronous. Manipulating the bits around to form a numeric value should present too much problem.

Comment: @KDM How do you know when the data is valid?  How do you know if there is a new reading if it happens to be the same as the last reading?

Comment: Ah... When a pulse arrives, it is captured by a peak detector, Held and an interrupt is presented to the processor. it will be sampled, fast sorted i.e. the value IS the array pointer and the energy counter is incremented. when this is done the hardware is reset for the next pulse. The faster this is done the higher the count rate and the less missed 'low count ' events missed. all done in a priority routine (like an old school interrupt). Higher level functions can suffer. wont need them until sampling is done.

Comment: @joan don't see the link between synchronicity and validation / notification. I've put my hands up to potentially misunderstanding, but "clocking in bits" is normally the process where a clock signal is sent along with the data signal and tells the recipient to absorb the next bit. Wait a minjte: are you saying that the problem with parallel data is the LACK of ability to clock it in? If so, I agree and asynchronous fixed-size, fixed-rate data is the only way to go.

Comment: @KDM I'm just saying you need to know when new data is available to be read.  I2C and SPI do that my changing a clock line.  A general serial link does it by enforcing a strict timing with messages of a defined size.  A strobe bit may be used to perform a similar role for parallel data, e.g. on strobe low to high transition the parallel data is stable and may be read.

Answer (score 1):

Todd, I've faced a similar issue, for ultrasound signal acquisition. Basically, you may want to explore the way the GPIOs of the Pi are mapped to its memory - but once it's done you just have to reorganize the bits and reconstruct your signal.

I would recommend [this article](https://digibird1.wordpress.com/raspberry-pi-as-an-oscilloscope-10-msps/) as it describes quite well the way parallel ADCs are managed and mapped to memory, resulting in a 10Msps+ acquisition. And for the fun of it, you can interleave two ADCs, clocked by the Pi, and get [up to 20Msps+](https://hackaday.io/project/20455-20msps-adc-raspberrypi-hat).

Answer (score 0):

Todd, you possibly should back up and rethink the problem.  I have worked on a series of data collection systems that have looked at the spectra from NaI(Tl) and BGO.  The resolution of these detectors is such that you are kidding yourself trying to look at a higher resolution than 8 bits.  Our systems accumulates the data from the detector in a remote memory (like the internal memory in a microcontroller) and only transmits the data block serially once a second. That would be 256 channels with 16 bit wide data.  Even if you could manage count rates of 1 million counts per second, unless they were all in a few channels (causing overflow of the 16 bit data) you could transmit your entire spectrum with only 4096 bits of data per second.  That would be pretty simple for any Pi, or even any Arduino for that matter.  If the update rate is not high enough, you could probably get away with sending the samples every quarter second.  It complicates the hardware a bit, but if you are good enough to design an A/D converter and signal conditioning circuits that can handle a million counts a second plus solve the nonlinearity issues of the detectors at such a high count rate the addition of a microcontroller would be trivial.

Comment: Yes currently using, Bicron BC412. It may very well be that I am expecting unrealistic count rates but transmission is not the problem as I plan to keep the dataset in local ram as the Pi has plenty and process it after I gather it. As for resolution I have the bad(?) habit of gathering more than I can use and filtering it after I gather it because I can always throw it out. What would be a reasonable count rate? also the conversion time is almost more important to minimize the sag in the sample-hold. -continued-

Comment: -continued-  I think that concerns me the most right now. Any advice would be appreciated as this is a diy Gamma-ray spectrometer. The "soundcard" version didn't make me happy (grin).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at USB FIFO chips, like [UM245R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_UM245R.pdf). They allow you to sample 8 bits at a time at pretty high rates, and transfer that data via USB at very decent speeds (UM245R datasheet advertises data rates up to 1 MB/s). FTDI also provides drivers for Linux, including [Raspberry Pi](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/libftd2xx-arm-v6-hf-1.3.6.tgz).

[image]